# Saving a workspace variable to the path selected with uigetcontrol (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I have some code that begins with

```
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.mat','Please select your data',...
'Multiselect','on');
```

and it goes on to calculate and store a variable in the workspace called "results".

I want to save "results" into the folder that the user selected their data from at the beginning, I've tried this:

```
save(pathname/'merge.mat');
```

and a few other things but I can't get it to work

Comment: `save(fullfile(pathname,'merge.mat'), 'name_of_the_data');` maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
save([pathname 'merge.mat']);
```

You need to concatenate the pathname string to 'merge.mat' and for that you must use square brackets [string1 string2].